# Finding the 8 Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}, i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

[image]

I think I will have i with root that identity ,then -the root,-i with root ,the root alone 
I cannot understand finding 8 ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$ is the splitting field for $f(x) = x^4 - 2$, and because finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are separable, $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension.  Thus, $|\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})| = [K:\mathbb{Q}] = 8$.  So indeed there must be $8$ automorphisms.  Thinking of these automorphisms in terms of their action on the roots of $f$, we can define one "base" automorphism, $\phi$, as follows:

$$\phi(\sqrt[4]{2}) = i\sqrt[4]{2}$$
$$\phi(i) = i$$

We can define another "base" automorphism, $\tau$, as follows:

$$\tau(i) = -i$$
$$\tau(\sqrt[4]{2}) = \sqrt[4]{2}$$

And, of course, we have the identity automorphism.  Note that $\phi$ generates $3$ non-identity automorphisms under composition with itself.  Next, we can generate more by composing $\phi$ with $\tau$ in a variety of ways.  So, all told, here are the $8$:

$$\{\text{id}, \phi, \phi^2, \phi^3, \tau, \phi \tau, \phi^2 \tau, \phi^3 \tau \}$$

If you plot the roots of $x^4-2$ in the complex plane, notice these can be thought of as vertices of a square; visually, we can see that $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong D_4$, wherein $\phi$ provides the rotation and $\tau$ the reflection.

Comment: so what  Ø^2 will be? if  Ø(forth root of 2)=i *forth root of 2 and  Ø(i)=i and i want the square it will be ( Ø(forth root of 2))^2=-sqrt(2) and Ø(i)=-1 is that correct?

Comment: It's kind of difficult parsing what you're trying to say without LaTeX, but if $\phi(\sqrt[4]{2}) = i\sqrt[4]{2}$, then $\phi^2(\sqrt[4]{2}) = \phi(i\sqrt[4]{2}) = \phi(i)\phi(\sqrt[4]{2}) = i \cdot i\sqrt[4]{2} = -\sqrt[4]{2}$.  Note that $\phi$ fixes $i$.

Comment: sorry u just take square for  Ø what about the right side should i square ϕ(i4√2) ?

Comment: Because $\phi^2$ represents composing $\phi$ with itself.  That is, $\phi^2(a) = \phi(\phi(a))$.  It doesn't represent squaring both sides.

Comment: do u figure out{ ϕ(4√2)=i4√‾2
ϕ(i)=i
We can define another "base" automorphism, τ, as follows:

τ(i)=−i
τ(4√‾2)=4√‾2} from the hint?since i cannot understand the hint ?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of complements to the previous answer.

By Eisenstein's criterion, the polynomial $x^4 - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, thus $\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}): \mathbb{Q} \rvert = 4$. Clearly $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, so that $\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \rvert = 2$, and
$$
\lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i): \mathbb{Q}| = \lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}) \rvert  \cdot \lvert \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}): \mathbb{Q} \rvert = 2 \cdot 4 = 8.
$$
Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$ is the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of a separable polynomial, you know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i) / \mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension, and that the Galois group has order $8$, the same as the degree.

Also, any root of a rational polynomial is sent to another root of the same polynomial by an automorphism (that automatically fixes the rationals).

Hence if $\sigma$ is an automorphism, the candidates for the images of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ under $\sigma$ are $\sqrt[4]{2}, - \sqrt[4]{2}, i \sqrt[4]{2}, -i \sqrt[4]{2}$, and the candidates for the images of $i$ are $i, -i$. As you see, there are $4 \cdot 2 = 8$ possibilities. Since the Galois group has order $8$, all these $8$ possibilities are realized, and you get the eight automorphisms given by
$$
\sqrt[4]{2} \mapsto \begin{cases}\sqrt[4]{2}\\ - \sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \sqrt[4]{2}\\ -i \sqrt[4]{2}\end{cases}
\qquad
i \mapsto \begin{cases}i\\ -i\end{cases}
$$

Comment: so what Ø^2 will be? if Ø(forth root of 2)=i *forth root of 2 and Ø(i)=i and i want the square it will be ( Ø(forth root of 2))^2=-sqrt(2) and Ø(i)=-1 is that correct?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$, otherwise what you write is hard to follow - just look at how the answers have been written - and I assume you want to take the square $\varphi^{2} = \varphi \circ \varphi$. Anyway, if $\varphi(\sqrt[4]{2}) = i \sqrt[4]{2}$, and $\varphi(i) = i$, then $\varphi^{2}(i)  = \varphi(i) = i$, and $\varphi^{2}(\sqrt[4]{2}) = \varphi(i \sqrt[4]{2}) = \varphi(i) \varphi(\sqrt[4]{2}) = i i \sqrt[4]{2} = - \sqrt[4]{2}$.

Comment: can you please tell me  what the fixed field will be ,u know we have to find the subfield first .I knoe

Comment: can you please tell how we find fix(H) of subgroup of D4 .I know we have subgroup of D4 are {id} {ϕ,ϕ^2,ϕ^3 ,id},{ϕ^2,id},{ϕ^3,ϕ^2,ϕ,id}{τ,id}{ϕτ,id}{ϕ^2τ,id}{ϕ^3τ,id},{id,ϕ^2τ,ϕ^2,τ}{ϕ^2,ϕτ,ϕ^3τ,id} and whole group we have 10 subgroup set D4

Comment: @user146264, please, use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: sorry but i do not know how to use it:(

Comment: Just look for instance at the $\LaTeX$ source of Kaj Hansen's answer. Please.