# Finding the splitting field of $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Let $E$ be the splitting field for $x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that $E=\mathbb{Q}[i + \sqrt[4]{2}]$.

I have a **hint**: Find at least five different elements in the orbit of $i + \sqrt[4]{2}$ under $\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$.

First, by Eisenstein criterion  $x^4-2$ is irreducible and its roots in $E$ are $\sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}, i\sqrt[4]{2}, -i\sqrt[4]{2}$. $f$ has distinct roots, so $f$ is separable over $E$. I have the following theorem: if $E$ is a splitting field over $F$ for some separable polynomial over $F$, then $E$ is a Galois extension of $F$. By this theorem, $E$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now I have the following sequence $$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]=E $$ and $|\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}] : \mathbb{Q}|=4$ , $|\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i] : \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]|=2$ , hence $|E:\mathbb{Q}|=8$. By Fundamental theorem of Galois Theory, $|\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})|=8$.

My question is that how can i show that  $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i] = \mathbb{Q}[i + \sqrt[4]{2}]$ by using hint above.

Comment: If $\mathbb{Q}[i+\sqrt[4]{2}]$ were a proper subset, what would its index be?

Comment: Good work so far.  Of course, since $\sqrt[4]{2} + i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$, so we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2} + i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$; hence to show that these fields are equal, it suffices to show that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(i + \sqrt[4]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is also $8$

Comment: Now, to find elements in the orbit of $\sqrt[4]{2} + i$, a good next step would be to find the elements of the Galois group explicitly.  You may find my post here helpful, but be forewarned of spoilers! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221706/simple-extension-of-mathbbq-sqrt42-i/2221711#2221711

Comment: The number of elements in the orbit should divide the order of the group.  If you've found at least five, then the orbit must have length 8.

Comment: Let $a=i+2^{1/4}$ so that $(a-i) ^{4}=2$ which expresses $i$ as a rational function of $a$ and then $2^{1/4}=a-i$ is also a rational function of $a$ so that $\mathbb{Q} (i, 2^{1/4})\subset \mathbb{Q} (i+2^{1/4})$.

Comment: @KajHansen how can i determine the elements of $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ explicitly. If I know these automorphism, then I can complete the proof by using nice hint. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @H.B.Ozcan It boils down to the fact that, if $K/F$ is a galois extension, then any $a \in K$ has a minimal polynomial whose roots are precisely the elements in the orbit of $a$ under the action of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$.  Of course, number of roots of the minimal polynomial is equal to the degree of that poly which is equal to the degree of the extension $F(a)$ over $F$.  For more details on this, see my link above.

Comment: As for determining the Galois group, use the fact that a Galois group is determined by its action on the roots of the associated polynomial.  In this case, those roots are the ones you listed.  Since the polynomial is irreducible, this action is transitive.  In particular, we can send $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to *any other root*.  Try doing this for different choices of root, and then compose that automorphism with itself to get even more automorphisms.  Also, it's worth noting that whenever a polynomial has complex roots, complex conjugation is *always* a valid automorphism.

Comment: So again, compose complex conjugation with other automorphisms you find to get even more automorphisms.  You can find all $8$ if you want, but per @sharding4's comment, it suffices to just find $5$.  I'd recommend finding all $8$ though because it's a good exercise.

Comment: If you get stuck finding the automorphisms, you can reference my post below, but do try to give it a stab before giving up:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779229/finding-the-8-automorphisms-of-mathbbq-sqrt42-i/779232#779232